# What does the writing on Poe's helmet say?

Tags: star-wars, poe-dameron

What does this writing on Poe Dameron's helmet say?

[image: side of Poe Dameron's helmet]

Answer (score 16):

**It spells "Roæhal"** which may be a signature of [Senior Prop Modeller](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2488496/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ov_st_sm) [**Roy Hal**fpenny](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm2823866/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cr229).  Thanks to Valorum for pointing this out.

I haven't been able to find any clean images of the actual prop from the movies that show the lettering in full, but the official Disney/Hasbro replica shows this:
[image: Poe Dameron replica helmet box]

I found an unboxing video that has a better view of the text:
[image: Text on replica helmet]

According to the Aurebesh alphabet:
[image: Star Wars Aurebesh alphabet]

It spells "Roæhal."

Comment: One Reddit user (probably misguidedly) hypothesized that the text is meant to be "RO & HAL," which would presumably be the initials of a concept artist and a significant other. A quick search of TFA's cast didn't turn up anyone who fit that bill.

Comment: **Roy Hal**fpenny- senior prop modeller; https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2488496/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ov_st_sm

Comment: @Valorum Not that I'm saying you're wrong, but why use Enth instead of Yirt?

Comment: @DavidW - To make it look more "space-y", probably. I'm planning to make this into a separate answer, but I'd honestly prefer if you added this info into your own.

Comment: @Valorum Thanks for finding this; I've updated the answer.